# correctly making use of inheritance in Android

Tags: android, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a *"Header"* at the top of 3 lists, which contains simple Create Read Update & Delete buttons for editing the list.

How should I go about subclassing the Header so I can overwrite the listener in TaskHeader, ProjectHeader, ClientsHeader (Subclasses)

seeing as the layout, button creation, assignment etc.. can all be done in the same implementaion and just assigning the listener can be delegated to the specific sub-class.

*Updated with suggested solution*

**Interface**

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public interface AttachClickListeners {

void attachCreateListener(OnClickListener l);
void attachReadListener(OnClickListener l);
void attachUpdateListener(OnClickListener l);
void attachDeleteListener(OnClickListener l);
```

}

**Header**

```
public class Header extends LinearLayout implements AttachClickListeners {
/* removed for shortness */
public void attachCreateListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    insertBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void attachReadListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void attachUpdateListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void attachDeleteListener(OnClickListener listener) {
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

then each time I create a header I just pass a different listener object as suggested by @elijah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the UI and behavior can be shared, you shouldn't have to subclass the header.

Instead, create interface definitions for listener classes for the events you want to respond to.  For instance, if you want to have different responses to the Create button, define a onCreateClickedListener interface, and then create particular instances of that interface for every view the shared header object exists in.  You have to register the listener; something like:

```
createClickedListener = new onCreateClickedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick() { ... }
};

header.setOnCreateClickedListener(createClickedListener);
```

[This](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/) tutorial covers the topic in depth.

Comment: Thanks the link was interesting - if I edit the question with my solution and maybe you could explain the advantages of the interfacing solution. I've done similar with an abstract class and then provided an abstract method - getListener() which the subclasses were overriding.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you're asking here.  If you edit the question I'm happy to look at it.  The advantages of the interfacing solution is that you don't have to subclass your header object -- and if you look at the Android framework, that's "how it's done"... otherwise we'd have to subclass every button, etc based on what we watned it to do.

Comment: I've updated the question to illustrate what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: well, again, in your solution every header needs to be subclassed.  Instead, refactor setupButtons to be four different setOnXClickedListener functions, which take an object which adheres to the OnXClickedListener interface.  Then each individual view can defined it's owns instances of the OnXClickedListener objects with their own onClick implementations and assign them to the Header instance in that view.

again, that's the "Android way", and while it does require creating implementations of the OnXClickedListeners, it avoids you having to subclass the entire header over and over.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, Having implemented it its made more sense why its preferable.